# Many-to-many relationship. How to search one common for 2 collections?

Tags: laravel, laravel-5, model, relationship

I have many-to-many relationship in my project.
user belongsToMany chats
and
chat belongsToMany users.

So, i have a pivot table chat_user with chat_id and user_id.

One chat can include some users as well

Its ok and works well.

When i`m creating a new Chat, i have 2 users. And i want to check, is there already common chat between them.

I have some problems with this query. 
I also tried to make custom model on chat_user table..but has no luck=(
May be someone has done such work? Is there any practicies? Thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One way is to use the [whereHas()](https://laravel.com/docs/5.6/eloquent-relationships#querying-relationship-existence) query builder method:

```php
$user1->chats()->whereHas('users', function($q) use ($user2) {
    $q->where('user_id', '=', $user2->id);
})->get();
```

As a best practice, I personally like to consolidate something like that onto the model (in this case your Chat model) as a [query scope](https://laravel.com/docs/5.6/eloquent#local-scopes) for easier use:

```
// class App\Chat
public function scopeWithUser($query, User $user)
{
    $query->whereHas('users', function ($q) use ($user) {
        $q->where('user_id', '=', $user->id);
    });
}
```

Then, you can use it like this:

```
// get common chats between user1 and user2
$user1->chats()->withUser($user2)->get();

// see if a common chat exists
$user1->chats()->withUser($user2)->exists();
```

which I think is very readable.

Answer (score 0):

The easiest way is probably to just take one user and look for the other. Assuming your relationships are correct, something like this:

```
$firstUserChats = $firstUser->chats()->pluck('user_id');
$usersHaveACommonChat = $firstUserChats->contains($secondUser->id);
```

While there are ways of doing this in one line, this is usually about as easy as it gets. :)